# .NET compiler limitation for addition?

Tags: .net, vb.net, jit

My co-worker and i just found that there seems to be a limitation on the number of parameters that can be used in vb.net code.

What's strange to me is that this code will build but when i run it, it throws an InvalidProgramException saying that the "JIT Compiler encountered an internal limitation".

Has anyone seen anything like this before? Can you point me to why this is happening?

(i'm using .net 4.0 with VS 2010. We found this in VS 2008 and it had a slightly different result.)

Sample code:

```
    Dim bigVariable As Double = 10.35
    Dim factor As Double = 1.3
    Dim hugeNumberOfArgs As Double = (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) +
(bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor) + (bigVariable * factor)

        Console.WriteLine("Result: " & hugeNumberOfArgs)
        Console.ReadKey()
```

Comment: possibly a bug, but definitively a misuse

Comment: It works fine in LINQPad.  `Result: 4534.33499999998`

Comment: Funny, it works in C# (after _converting_ to C#, of course...)

Comment: Lolz at @Jordão. Of course, now is not the time to be starting a C# vs VB war =D

Comment: And it _also_ works on VB.NET... I just checked in the command line with the "Visual Basic Compiler version 9.0.30729.1".

Comment: Ahahaha! It only fails in Debug mode - works in Release mode, hence why it works in, e.g., LINQPad.

Comment: Yes! It fails when compiling like this: `vbc /debug+ Program.vb`

Comment: i agree it's a misuse. One of our customers was using it and we showed her a better way, but i was surprised this would cause it to fail!

Comment: i'm finding that this will break if compiled for x86 but not x64. interesting!

Comment: i've found this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312544#appliesto but i'm not sure if it speaks to the same thing.

Comment: _And_ it __fails__ in C# with debug information: `csc /debug+ Program.cs`. So it's unlikely to be a compiler issue.

Comment: Also, all compiled programs (C#, VB.NET, release, debug) _pass_ [PEVerify](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62bwd2yd.aspx).

Comment: You don't need that many lines, 15 + 1 would suffice. Or 78 times `(bigVariable * factor)`... (using VS 2010, non-SP1, 64 bit system)

Comment: @Abel you're right, but that snippet is not meant to be good code. i'm just trying to break the system.

Comment: An explanation: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/653081/jit-compiler-issue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After further investigation I don't believe this is a compiler issue. The code crashes in Debug and works fine in Retail. I've diff'd the IL a few times and can't come across a discernable difference.

Also this bug repros in C# as well.  If you're trying to repro this yourself make sure you pass /debug+ to the command line compiler.

This appears to be a bug in the JIT compilation.  One way to prevent the crash in debug mode is to add the following line of code

```
<Assembly: Debuggable(DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.DisableOptimizations)>
```

Once this is added the code will execute successfully.  This and reproing in both languages strongly *suggests* that it's a bug in the JIT process.

Comment: would you mind sending me a link to the bug so i could follow it? i'm curious.

Comment: @Jugglingnutcase if they file a bug it will likely be internally.  However you can file this via http://connect.microsoft.com and they will keep it up to date with any progress they make.

Comment: i'll send a report there. Did you see my link in the comments above to that kb article? It seems to describe what i found but i would like to dig more into it.

Also, i see you're the VsVim guy! i've been considering trying it out and just started watching the github repo. i'll let you know what i think :)

Comment: @Jugglingnutcase i looked at the KB article and it doesn't seem to cover this case. The code AFAICT is correct. I'm fairly convinced it's an actual JIT compiler issue at this point.